# reactivate saveDocView Buttons in TYPO3 9

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

In TYPO3 9 the save and view button for tt_content and pages is missing. I tried reactivating it via user.ts:

```
options.saveDocView.tt_content = 1
options.saveDocView.pages = 1
```

Unfortunately nothing happens. Can someone help? Alternatively, is it possible to view the whole TCEMAIN config somewhere as you can with the TCA? Maybe I could go search there...

Comment: TCEMAIN, TCEFORM, TSFE, RTE, MOD,... is viewed in backend module `Info` whith selected `Page TSconfig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you're looking for has been removed.
With TYPO3 version 9LTS a new concept for save document buttons was introduced.
See epic issue "Save Button Gate" on forge https://forge.typo3.org/issues/84751
See also concept here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Pr85TllSeuYvy5pxUz9A2k-YFrJNW5J5FuCVpuPkYPY.

`options.saveDocView` will just handle visibility of the single view-button for current document.

`options.saveDocView = 1` is default for TYPO3 v9LTS.

`options.saveDocView.pages = 0` fx. will override defaults and disable the view-button for entries of table pages.

Comment: while I get it that the old buttons were hard(er) for beginners, completely removing them is a very bad workflow choice imho. it would be better to deactivate them and have the possibility to activate them for a usergroup via TS ... Wonder why anyone thought it was a good idea to force users to click twice every time :(